# How to add a PNG image on a PDF using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a PDF and I want to keep all the content and put a image on it.

To add text to the PDF, I've used CombinePDF gem, but it seems like it does not support images.
I've also tried using prawn gem, but it creates a new empty file with the png instead of adding the new content.

It is possible to simply add a PNG image on a PDF?
Or is it possible to add a PDF (like the one I created with prawn) and add it "above" another PDF (like the original)?

Comment: Finally was able to make it. HexaPDF did the job:
```
  doc = HexaPDF::Document.open(pdf_path)
  page = doc.pages[1]
  canvas = page.canvas(type: :overlay)
  canvas.image(png_path, at: [350, 52], height: 27)```

Answer (score 0):

The gem you have used is for combining multiple PDF files into single file.
You can create a new PDF file using the wicked_pdf gem and generate the related view, for images use the absolute path of the image like

```
<%= image_tag "#{Rails.root.join('public','yourimagename.png')}",size: '100x100', class: 'sign-img' %>
```

Then you can combine the generated PDF.